# Is it possible for org-publish to ignore certain sub-directories?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

I am working on managing my website with `ox-twbs`. The directory tree of my site looks like this:

```
mysite/
├── bar
│   └── private
├── foo
│   ├── eggs
│   │   └── private
│   └── spam
└── img
```

I want `org-publish` to ignore all files under a directory named `private`. Is this possible?

My project in my `.emacs` looks like this

```
(let ((proj-base (file-name-directory load-file-name)))
  (setq org-publish-project-alist
    `(("org"
       :base-directory "~/mysite/"
       :recursive t
       :publishing-directory "~/published-pages/"
       :exclude ????
       :publishing-function org-twbs-publish-to-html)
      ("static"
       :base-directory "~/mysite/"
       :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|txt"
       :publishing-directory "~/published-pages/"
       :recursive t
       :exclude ????
       :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)
      ("website" :components ("org" "static"))
      ))
```

My guess is that I can exclude everything under a directory named `private` with something like `:exclude "*/private/*"` but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:exclude` property should do the trick.

I think the reason the property is not working for you is because its value [should form a regular expression](http://orgmode.org/manual/Selecting-files.html#Selecting-files), whereas your example is a [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Try using `:exclude ".*/private/.*"` or similar.

See also the GNU Emacs Manual node on [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html) for the particularities of its syntax.

Comment: Note that the exclude syntax is _relative to the base directory_. So don't include the base directory itself in the pattern.